# Move a file and re-target all of its symlinks

Tags: bash, files, symlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I “relink” a lot of broken symlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/how-can-i-relink-a-lot-of-broken-symlinks)

Is there any way to move a file to a new location, and then re-target its symlinks to the new location, using a shell script? I'd like to find a way to move a file programmatically without breaking its symlinks.