# How to Relink these symlinks after moving the system?

Tags: find, symlink, ln

I moved my filesystem and symlinks from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 by using FAT32 memory card, which apparently broke those links; stopped using BitTorrentSync. Differential condition is that those links are remnants of my OSX installation because of XSym. I do `ls -la $HOME | grep Math` for a symlink

```
-rw-r--r--  1 masi masi   1067 May 17 21:28 Math
```

which contents in the text-editor

```
XSym
0078
48055bd2d9c13568c969e1eb8d6a22ac
/Users/masi/Math/
```

It should point to `/Users/masi/LOREM/Math/` instead. 
Just correcting manually the PATH does not work, since the link stays death.
[Gilles' command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18365/16920) can be applicable here too:

```
find /Users/masi/Math/ /
    -lname '/Users/masi/LOREM/Math/*' \ 
    -exec sh -c 'ln -snf "/mnt$(readlink "$0")" "$0"' {} \;
```

where I am not sure if I got the source and destination in the correct order.

Systems: Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: That doesn't seem to look like a regular symlink. (Those look like this: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 itvirta  staff  6 Jun 13 15:39 testlink -> foobar`). The text file seems to match a description of how Mac OS X saves symbolic links on DOS/FAT filesystems. I don't think Linux supports those on vfat filesystems, and otherwise you would have real native symlinks. (Unless some desktop environments use special text files as "links" (?))

Comment: So, if it's not a real symlink, the usual tools (`find -lname` and `readlink`) are not going to find it. Also, I can't tell if you need to change them to regular symlinks or edit in that format.

Comment: Why not just add a new link with `ln -s Math /users/masi/Mathematics` so that all path names starting with `/Users/masi/Mathematics` automatically resolve by replacing that prefix with `/Users/masi/Math` ?

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Sorry, I changed names for clarity because I got confused myself. So you mean `ln -s $HOME/Math/ $HOME/LOREM/Math/` i.e. to create a new symlink. Yes, that is a replacement of an old link with a new one. I have many such links etc Physics, Chemistry, ... in a similar fashion. I am thinking how I could handle it in practice. The manual replacement may be the only way to do it here. It is however not what I would like to have. I would like to have a continuous monitoring about those links, and suggestions for fixes. My systems break often, and they are big. Manual means work.

Comment: Upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 wouldn't have broken the symlinks. Also, if you say that your "systems break often" then there's something else at work here. On what type of filesystem are these broken symlinks located?

Comment: Regarding your example. 1. Is your home directory `/Users/masi`? You reference `$HOME` along with absolute paths but nothing explicitly ties one to the other. 2. The file-that-should-be-a-symlink-but-isn't contains `/Users/masi/Math/`. How do you determine that it should really point to`/Users/masi/LOREM/Math/`? 3. What determines that a file is supposed to be replaced with a symlink?

Comment: @roaima 1. Home directory is `/Users/masi`. 2. It should really point to `/Users/masi/Lorem/Math` because I know my system and the correposding directory is there. 3. I do not know. Do you?

Comment: @roaima You can assume simply that I changed the directory structure, which broke the symlink. I mean by that my symlinks break often that I change my directory structure often so they break therefore often.

Comment: There aren't any symlinks in your question though, broken or otherwise

Comment: Apparently these XSym files are created by MacOS when trying to create symlinks on a filesystem that isn't capable of storing symlinks, like FAT32: https://books.google.de/books?id=K8vUkpOXhN4C&pg=PA1390&lpg=PA1390&dq=mac+softlink+%22xsym%22&source=bl&ots=OLnlQXVwVw&sig=QJiqdJzY9-2bs2xGczXlEIHs8uQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie6bz2267NAhVHOBQKHfaHBjYQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=mac%20softlink%20%22xsym%22&f=false

Comment: @MartinvonWittich These files were created on Ubuntu. I think messed up the thing, by moving all my files in FAT32 memory card, and to new Ubuntu system. This way also symlinks broke. Does it help the case?

Comment: @Masi I don't think that Ubuntu created these XSym files (or even can create them). Also the destination path from your example (/Users/masi/Math/) wouldn't be a valid destination path on Ubuntu - /Users is MacOS, on Ubuntu it would be /home.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich Ok. Is there any change of correcting those?

Comment: The two scripts I have (already) given you don't rely on `/Users` or `/home`. Have you tried them yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions that spring to mind.

**1. Iterate across all the directories in `LOREM` and symlink them to `$HOME`**

```
cd "$HOME/LOREM"
for item in *
do
    test -d "$item" || continue
    mv -f "$HOME/$item" "$HOME/$item.DELETE_ME_LATER" 2>/dev/null
    ln -s "$HOME/LOREM/$item" "$HOME/$item"
done

# Once you are happy that only the correct files have been replaced
# rm "$HOME"/*.DELETE_ME_LATER
```

You can prefix the `rm` and `ln` with `echo` (eg `echo rm -f "Users/masi/$item"`) to see the effect of the script before it makes any changes

**2. Process the set of existing files and convert them to proper symlinks**

This one will need some heuristics (guesswork), because there is nothing concrete that identifies a file-that-should-be-a-symlink.

Something like this might work

```
for file in *
do
    # Skip files that we have already processed
    [[ $file =~ DELETE_ME_LATER ]] && continue

    # Look for a path-like string in the file
    path=$(grep "^$HOME/" "$file")
    if test -d "$path"
    then
        # It is a directory
        mv -f "$file" "$file.DELETE_ME_LATER"
        ln -s "$HOME/LOREM/$file" "$file"
    fi
done

# Once you are happy that only the correct files have been replaced
# rm *.DELETE_ME_LATER
```

Again, you can prefix the `mv` and `ln` statements with `echo` to see the effect without applying any changes.

Comment: @Masi the second script reads the contents of the files as described by you in your question. Stick `echo` in front of the `mv` and `ln` commands and give it whirl. If they don't parse the not-really-symlinks-at-all files get me a real one and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @roiama I am trying to understand the severity of those `XSym` things. I can find matches of them all over my system. XSym probable means also other things too than symlinks.

Comment: @Masi I've never come across these `XSym` files before. You described them as symlinks. They're not Unix/Linux symlinks but it seems from other people's comments that they might be something a Mac produces (like Windows "shortcuts", perhaps, which also aren't symlinks). If they're readable files and they're on a filesystem that can use proper symlinks my code is intended to be able to read them and replace them with the equivalent symlinks as per my understanding of your question.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output of one symlink which your file does, please.

Comment: @Masi, put `echo` in front of the `mv` and `ln` commands so that they become no-ops, and run either of the scripts directly on your system. That will give you first-hand results that you can feed back as necessary. I've offered you an answer; please try it.

Comment: Is `echo -e "yourCode" sufficient`? Is this `for item in *` too general?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just amplifying information that's too big for a comment.

Those `XSym` files are explained (somewhat) [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/UNIX_Extensions#Minshall.2BFrench_symlinks).

The original poster doesn't mention this in the context of the original question, but I'm guessing that Léo's filesystem was on a NAS (or other home networking server), running Samba, accessed from a Mac. Hence the symlinks that are not actually symlinks.

I'm not 100% positive whether it's the macOS version of `ln` or Samba itself that writes those fake-symlink files; my guess is Samba, but the document linked above isn't clear on that. The long and short of it is they're way of supporting symlinks for Unix clients on SMB/CIFS filesystems.