# Repair broken symlinks to new location

Tags: bash, symlink

I moved from an old webserver to a new one.
Now some symlinks not working, because we changed the folder structur.
I want to know if there is a easy way to repair these links?
I found the links with this command:

```bsh
find -L . -type l -ls
```

The links looks like this:

```bsh
./example/vondercode/releases/example.com/2.0/www/img/uploads -> /home/example/vondercode/uploads
./example2/www/img/uploads -> /home/example2/vondercode/uploads
```

Now the links must look like this:

```bsh
./example/vondercode/releases/example.com/2.0/www/img/uploads -> /var/www/html/example/vondercode/uploads
./example2/www/img/uploads -> /var/www/html/example2/vondercode/uploads
```

So easy to say, all `/home` should be replaced by `/var/www/html`
Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I "relink" a lot of broken symlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/how-can-i-relink-a-lot-of-broken-symlinks)

Answer (score 2):

if it is "just replace /home with /var/www/html" then this approach should work:

```
find . -type l -exec sh -c 'lnk="{}"; target="$(readlink '{}' | sed 's#/home#/var/www/html#')"; unlink "${lnk}"; ln -s "${target}" "${lnk}" ' \;
```

Thanks for Toby Speight to point out that the first version did not work as expected - this is fixed now.

Comment: You'll need to remove the existing links or use `ln -sf` to overwrite them. However, since this can be destructive if it goes wrong, I would suggest first echoing the commands to make sure they do what you expect and then running them.

Comment: This is vulnerable to filename injection - prefer to pass `{}` as a shell script _argument_: 
`find . -type l -exec sh -c 'p=$(realpath "$1"); rm "$1" && ln -s "${p/#\/home//var/www/html}" "$1"' sh {} \;`

Comment: Actually, it's completely broken, as `realpath {}` is executed far too early - this will just remove all your links and the `ln` commands will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool. You can use it like this:

```bash
fix_broken_symlinks . /home /var/www/html --force
```

See full details in my main answer here: [How can I "relink" a lot of broken symlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732315/114401)