# Depmod command not found but kmod is already installed

Tags: debian, command-line, terminal, gnome, command-not-found

When I use depmod in the terminal, I got the message "depmod command not found". But kmod is already installed.
And I can find a link to something called depmod in sbin.
Do you know how to solve this?

I use Debian 11 GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Check the `depmod` command location:

`ls -l /sbin/depmod`

If the link is broken, you can recreate it using the following command:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/depmod /sbin/depmod`

[How can I "relink" a lot of broken symlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/how-can-i-relink-a-lot-of-broken-symlinks)

[How can I find broken symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34248/how-can-i-find-broken-symlinks)

**Option 2**

Check if you can call `depmod` with `/sbin/depmod`

Check if the `/sbin` directory is included in your system's `PATH` variable

`echo $PATH`

If it's not, you can add it temporarily to your current session:

`export PATH=$PATH:/sbin`

To make this permanent, add the line `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin` to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file

[What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

[Add /usr/local/sbin to the PATH of a user](https://superuser.com/questions/595818/add-usr-local-sbin-to-the-path-of-a-user)